# Laravel: how can i hide the users' uploaded files from myself if they are being uploaded to my public folder

Tags: laravel, file-upload

I am working on a diary web app and was wondering if developers of such pages can spy on our uploaded files like images or videos

Comment: The best way to get a useable answer is to ask a question showing that you actually tried something, and can give us things like code and error messages to help you.

Comment: in Laravel we store files to the public folder so we can retrieve it later, but then if users upload their files, I can see them in the public folder, is there something I am missing?